# Drone CI is not logging me out

Tags: github, drone.io, gitea

I am using Drone for self hosted CI, and have currently set it up for gitea, which I host myself as well, and github. I would like to have CI for both services, and have configured my docker-compose file as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:latest

    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone/
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_OPEN=false
      - DRONE_HOST=https://<my-drone-domain>
      - DRONE_GITEA=true
      - DRONE_GITEA_URL=https://<my-gt-domain>
      - DRONE_GITEA_GIT_USERNAME=<gh-user>
      - DRONE_GITEA_GIT_PASSWORD=<gh-pass>
      - DRONE_SECRET=<secret>
      - DRONE_GITHUB=true
      - DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT=<gh-client>
      - DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET=<gh-secret>
      - DRONE_GITHUB_URL=https://github.com
      - DRONE_GITHUB_SCOPE=repo,repo:status,user:email,read:org
      - DRONE_GITHUB_PRIVATE_MODE=false
      - DRONE_GITHUB_CONTEXT=continuous-integration/drone
      - DRONE_GITHUB_SKIP_VERIFY=false


  drone-agent:
    image: drone/agent:latest

    command: agent
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=drone-server:9000
      - DRONE_SECRET=<secret>
```

When I try to log out of the github account on drone, it instantly logs me back in, and on a device I have never before logged in, I can't even get to any login form, because my authorization token is obviusly invalid / not yet generated.

Comment: A sort of workaround would be to have a seperate instance of drone running for each service one would want to run. 2 drone instances should not leave that much of a footprint, but it will get worse from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comment above, this is the way I roll now. Using two seperate drone instances, one for each version control system. I would not call it ideal, but it works just fine and drone does not use a lot of resources.